# Calculate sample size and replications for heuristic simulation

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, simulation

I want to confirm the goodness of fit of a heuristic which aims to find a minimum of a model. Therefore, I want to do a complete enumeration of the possible parameters with an simulation to find the true optimum which the heuristic should find.

My problem is now how to determine the number of periods the simulation has to run and also the number of replications I need. The random numbers I use when I run the simulation are e. g. poisson distributed.

For the number of replications I already found this formula, which calculates the half-width (where n is the number of periods in the simulation?): 
$h = z_{\left(1 - \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)} \cdot \dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

Which I would use in this formula, where $h_0$ is the initial half-width, $n_0$ = initial number of replications, $h$ = target half-width, $n$ = number of replication required: $n = n_0 \cdot \dfrac{h_0^2}{h^2}$

I'm not quite sure whether this is the right approach and is there any better way to do it?